# jQuery How to use .not with this

Tags: jquery, if-statement, click, addclass, removeclass

I have a ticket system. Messages are placed in a div and that div has hidden sub messages (the replies of that ticket)

[Demo](http://www.gc-cdn.com/snippets/java.php)

[jsFiddle Hosted Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cs87W/)

Click an Arrow - shows the thread child. Click it again it hides the thread child and the arrow goes up and down.

I want it so that if the current thread is open, the user clicks the other arrow, the open arrow should restore back and vice versa.

**jQuery**

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('h1').click(function(){
            if ($(this).next('.parent').hasClass('showMe')){
                    $('.parent').removeClass('showMe').hide();
                    $(this).find("#ticket_arrow").removeClass('up');
                $(this).find("#ticket_arrow").addClass('down');
              } else {
                $('.parent').removeClass('showMe').hide();
                    $(this).find("#ticket_arrow").removeClass('down');
                $(this).find("#ticket_arrow").addClass('up');
                $(this).next('.parent').addClass('showMe').show();
            }
        });
    });
/**
  Hides all sub threads on Load
**/
$('.parent').hide();
```

**HTML**

```
<style type="text/css">
.ticket_thread_h1 span{cursor:pointer}
.down{background:url(http://www.gc-cdn.com/personalstylist/down.png) no-repeat;width:15px;height:10px;display:block}
.up{background:url(http://www.gc-cdn.com/personalstylist/up.png) no-repeat;width:15px;height:10px;display:block}
</style>
<h1 id="ticket_thread_1" class="ticket_thread_h1">Thread # 1 <span id="ticket_arrow" class="down">&nbsp;</span></h1>
<div class="parent">
    <div class="sub_thread"><p>Thread Messages #1 1</p></div>
    <div class="sub_thread"><p>Thread Messages #1 2</p></div>
</div>
<h1 id="ticket_thread_2" class="ticket_thread_h1">Thread # 2 <span id="ticket_arrow" class="down">&nbsp;</span></h1>
<div class="parent">
    <div class="sub_thread"><p>Thread Messages #2 1</p></div>
    <div class="sub_thread"><p>Thread Messages #2 2</p></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you create a fiddle? I tried but it didnt work with the code you provided.

Comment: So if a user clicks the arrow, current arrow goes up - all other page arrows go down and other threads hidden. If user clicks another arrow the current open arrow goes down and the new threads appear and that one is hidden? I want the same.. tricky but simple fix with not() it seems.

Comment: I added the jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cs87W/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following code :

```
$("h1").find('.up').each(function(){$(this).removeClass('up').addClass('down');});
```

after `$(this).find("#ticket_arrow").removeClass('down');` in `else` part, so code must be :

```
$('h1').click(function(){
            if ($(this).next('.parent').hasClass('showMe')){
                $('.parent').removeClass('showMe').hide();
                $(this).find("#ticket_arrow").removeClass('up');
                $(this).find("#ticket_arrow").addClass('down');
              } else {
                $('.parent').removeClass('showMe').hide();
                $(this).find("#ticket_arrow").removeClass('down');
                $("h1").find('.up').each(function(){$(this).removeClass('up').addClass('down');});
                $(this).find("#ticket_arrow").addClass('up');
                $(this).next('.parent').addClass('showMe').show();
            }
        });
```

that's work for me.

**Edit**: BTW, why you have a multiple elements with same ID ?

Comment: You legend.. It has taken 4 hours to recode this to jQuery and this was a frustrating part. I have reduced so much down. Thankyou.

Comment: Those were just psuedo code. Will sort in development phase when integrating WebSphere Commerce.

Comment: @TheBlackBenzKid , thank you, you need just to fall in love with jQueru, so jQuery will love you too and give you a solutions itself using your mind :P, btw, just look at my edit :)

Answer (score 0):

Just store a reference to the last displayed item.

It doesn't loop through all possible messages, because that is inefficient and is relatively expensive.
Note that I didn't verify this in jQuery, be my guest.

```
var lastOpenItem = undefined;

$('h1').click(function(){

    if( lastOpenItem ) {
        lastOpenItem.removeClass('showMe');

        var curSelect = $(this).next('.parent');
        lastOpenItem = ( curSelect == lastOpenItem ) ? undefined : curSelect;
    }
});
```

On top of that, your code seems redundant to me, as it has twice the same line in both IF and ELSE. I would suggest moving it out of the condition.

```
$('.parent').removeClass('showMe').hide();
```

I would honestly give your classnames semantic names (up, down,showMe vs. activeMessage, arrowExpand, whatever), but oh well.

I would also regroup your HTML, because your dynamic ID's with numbers are not.. so nice.

Lastly, you don't have to toggle 2 classes. Give the arrow the class "arrow" or something, and the CSS can be toggled by it's parent state, since they are mutually bounded.

HTML:

```
<h1 id="ticket_thread_2" class="ticket_thread_h1 activeMessage">Thread # 2 <span class="ticket_arrow">&nbsp;</span></h1>
<div class="parent">
    <div class="sub_thread"><p>Thread Messages #2 1</p></div>
    <div class="sub_thread"><p>Thread Messages #2 2</p></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.ticket-arrow{

    background:url(http://www.gc-cdn.com/personalstylist/down.png) no-repeat;
    width: 15px;
    height:10px;
    display:block

}
.activeMessage>.arrow {

    background-image:url(http://www.gc-cdn.com/personalstylist/up.png);
}​
```

I do find it uncommon to use absolute urls for images, I think you should copy them local, unless you wish them to change when gc-cdn.com does change them too..

Answer (score 0):

Here's another working version - a bit cleaner.

HTML markup - added `.arrow` class and fixed IDs:

```
<h1 id="ticket_thread_1" class="ticket_thread_h1">Thread # 1 <span id="ticket_arrow1" class="arrow down">&nbsp;</span></h1>
<div class="parent">
    <div class="sub_thread"><p>Thread Messages #1 1</p></div>
    <div class="sub_thread"><p>Thread Messages #1 2</p></div>
</div>
<h1 id="ticket_thread_2" class="ticket_thread_h1">Thread # 2 <span id="ticket_arrow2" class="arrow down">&nbsp;</span></h1>
<div class="parent">
    <div class="sub_thread"><p>Thread Messages #2 1</p></div>
    <div class="sub_thread"><p>Thread Messages #2 2</p></div>
</div>
```

JavaScript - cached selectors:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $arrows = $('.arrow');
    $parents = $('.parent');
    $('h1').click(function(){
        if ($(this).next('.parent').hasClass('showMe')){
           $parents.removeClass('showMe').hide();
           // Just in case make all arrows point down:
           $arrows.removeClass('up').addClass('down');
        } else {
           $parents.removeClass('showMe').hide();
           $arrows.removeClass('up').addClass('down');
           $(this).find('.arrow').addClass('up');
           $(this).next('.parent').addClass('showMe').show();
        }
    });
    /**
    Hides all sub threads
    **/
   $parents.hide();
});
```

Working jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jfrej/cs87W/8/

If you can, you should start using the latest jQuery. The version 1.3.2 in the jsfiddle is way out of date - I left it in to ensure my solution works with that version too.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('h1').click(function(){
  var $t = $(this);

  $t.siblings('h1').children('span').removeClass('up')
  .end().next().hide();

  $t.children('span').toggleClass('up')
  .end().next().toggle();
});
```

I would just style the arrow default as down (most items will have it this way) and toggle "up".

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cs87W/11/)

Comment: No offense but this chaining seems pretty horrible to me.

Comment: It's less code, it's probably faster and it works... but I made it a bit more readable for you ;).

Comment: It doesn't seem just as bad anymore, lol. I'm not that familiar with jQuery, so I guess the chaining freaked me out at first sight - particulairly end().end().
You could post the alternative too, as some people might prefer it nevertheless.

Comment: The alternative? There is none, .end() just selects the first element in the chain (e.g. $t = $(this)). Else I would get .next() of the arrow span inside h1...

Comment: I meant your code before you rewrote it for "me". Sorry if I was unclear :-)